# 'class' type redefinition error with header guards C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, error-handling, redefinition

To my understanding, header guards are used to avoid accidentally including something multiple times. However, when I include a class multiple times I still get a redefinition error. Shouldn't the header guards take care of this?
//animal.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define AMIMAL_H

class Animal {};

#endif
```

//main.cpp

```
#include"animal.h"
#include"animal.h"
```

---

Error C2011: 'Animal' : 'class' type redefinition

Comment: Active "generate preprocessed file" to see the actual output of the preprocessor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo, since a misspelling of `ANIMAL_H` --> `AMIMAL_H` is not useful to future readers.

Answer (score 6):

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define AMIMAL_H
         ^
```

Those aren't both `ANIMAL_H`.

Comment: Well spotted. I didn't see that, but then my eyesight isn't all that good.

Comment: This just caused me to go double check that I hadn't made the same mistake. Thanks... After literally breaking my head over it for ages, I had misspelled the `#define` statement.